# How to split integer-character pairs in python

Tags: python, python-re

I have a list,

```
['20W', '20W', '20W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '9W3K8W', '7W7R6W', '6W4R1Y4R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '8W5N7W']
```

and I am trying to work out how many integer-character pairs it contains. For example, `20W` is a pair, as is `1R` and `5K`. I tried using the regular expression `\d+[A-Z]` and this identifies the pairs, but how would I split them given that the integer can be any length and the string is always one letter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: have you considered using `^` and `$` to test the full string at once

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I would like to get the total number of pairs by taking the length of the list of split pairs

Comment: @Chase I am quite new to regex, what do they do?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
data = ['20W', '20W', '20W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '9W3K8W', '7W7R6W', '6W4R1Y4R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W',
    '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '8W5N7W']

for item in data:
    result = re.findall(r'\d+[A-Z]', item)
    print(item, len(result), result)
```

Output

```
20W 1 ['20W']
20W 1 ['20W']
20W 1 ['20W']
8W5K7W 3 ['8W', '5K', '7W']
8W5K7W 3 ['8W', '5K', '7W']
8W5K7W 3 ['8W', '5K', '7W']
8W5K7W 3 ['8W', '5K', '7W']
9W3K8W 3 ['9W', '3K', '8W']
7W7R6W 3 ['7W', '7R', '6W']
6W4R1Y4R5W 5 ['6W', '4R', '1Y', '4R', '5W']
6W1R1W5R1W1R5W 7 ['6W', '1R', '1W', '5R', '1W', '1R', '5W']
6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W 9 ['6W', '1R', '1W', '2R', '1Y', '2R', '1W', '1R', '5W']
6W1R1W5R1W1R5W 7 ['6W', '1R', '1W', '5R', '1W', '1R', '5W']
6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W 9 ['6W', '1R', '1W', '2R', '1Y', '2R', '1W', '1R', '5W']
9W3B8W 3 ['9W', '3B', '8W']
9W3B8W 3 ['9W', '3B', '8W']
9W3B8W 3 ['9W', '3B', '8W']
9W3B8W 3 ['9W', '3B', '8W']
9W3B8W 3 ['9W', '3B', '8W']
8W5N7W 3 ['8W', '5N', '7W']
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner, but without a bunch of unnecessary functions and looping. Since it is always one letter, what you are really asking is: "How many letters are there?". The numbers don't even matter at that point. The regex is also more efficient and dynamic than the similar answer by @Ronie. If for whatever reason the letters also included lowercase, this will not break.

```
import re

data = ['20W', '20W', '20W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '9W3K8W', '7W7R6W', '6W4R1Y4R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '8W5N7W']

pairs = len(re.findall('[a-z]', "".join(data), re.I))
print(pairs) #76
```

**edit**: the above code is completely different than the version my commenter was referring to.

### Complex Example With Full Statistical Reporting

```
import re

class Statistics:
    def __init__(self, data):
        format  = re.compile('\d+[a-z]', re.I)
        matches = format.finditer("".join(data))
        
        self.pairs = 0
        for m in matches:
            attr = getattr(self, m.group(), [0, []])
            attr[0] += 1
            attr[1].append(self.pairs)
            
            setattr(self, m.group(), attr)
            
            self.pairs += 1

    def __str__(self):
        attrs = vars(self)
        stats = f'{self.pairs} pairs were found:\n\n'
        
        for k, v in attrs.items():
            if k != 'pairs':
                percentage = round(len(v[1])/self.pairs*100, 2)
                stats = f'{stats}{k} appears {v[0]} times in positions {v[1]} and is {percentage}% of known values\n'
        
        return stats


data = ['20W', '20W', '20W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '8W5K7W', '9W3K8W', '7W7R6W', '6W4R1Y4R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W5R1W1R5W', '6W1R1W2R1Y2R1W1R5W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '9W3B8W', '8W5N7W']

stats = Statistics(data)

print(stats)
```

**output**

```
'''
76 pairs were found:

20W appears 3 times in positions [0, 1, 2] and is 3.95% of known values
8W appears 11 times in positions [3, 6, 9, 12, 17, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 73] and is 14.47% of known values
5K appears 4 times in positions [4, 7, 10, 13] and is 5.26% of known values
7W appears 6 times in positions [5, 8, 11, 14, 18, 75] and is 7.89% of known values
9W appears 6 times in positions [15, 58, 61, 64, 67, 70] and is 7.89% of known values
3K appears 1 times in positions [16] and is 1.32% of known values
7R appears 1 times in positions [19] and is 1.32% of known values
6W appears 6 times in positions [20, 21, 26, 33, 42, 49] and is 7.89% of known values
4R appears 2 times in positions [22, 24] and is 2.63% of known values
1Y appears 3 times in positions [23, 37, 53] and is 3.95% of known values
5W appears 5 times in positions [25, 32, 41, 48, 57] and is 6.58% of known values
1R appears 8 times in positions [27, 31, 34, 40, 43, 47, 50, 56] and is 10.53% of known values
1W appears 8 times in positions [28, 30, 35, 39, 44, 46, 51, 55] and is 10.53% of known values
5R appears 2 times in positions [29, 45] and is 2.63% of known values
2R appears 4 times in positions [36, 38, 52, 54] and is 5.26% of known values
3B appears 5 times in positions [59, 62, 65, 68, 71] and is 6.58% of known values
5N appears 1 times in positions [74] and is 1.32% of known values
'''
```

Comment: I think this will add 1 because of the letter at the end.

Answer (score 2):

1-liner + import:

```
import re

print(sum(len(re.findall("\\d+[A-Z]", i)) for i in x))  #76
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works great, what does the second \ at the start of the regex do?

Comment: a backslash (\\) is a special character which when combine with the next character creates a different one. `\n` is equivalent to a new line. \\ means it is a backslash.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry where did you get that? Single and double quotes are the same in python. Correction: "Double backslash is unnecessary if you only use raw strings".

Comment: Here is an interpreter output:
`>>> "\\a" == '\a'
False`